# Build error for every check-in’s. issue accessing dll. works locally

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Looks like multiple msbuild processes trying to access the file

> Summary
>
> Debug | Any CPU 6 error(s), 10 warning(s)  $/Development/SampleApp.sln
>   - 6 error(s), 10 warning(s)  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>   (3797): Unable to copy file
>   "D:\Builds\74\653\src\References\EntityFramework.dll" to
>   "D:\Builds\74\653\bin\EntityFramework.dll". Access to the path
>   'D:\Builds\74\653\bin\EntityFramework.dll' is denied. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>   (3797): Unable to copy file
>   "D:\Builds\74\653\src\References\EntityFramework.dll" to
>   "D:\Builds\74\653\bin\EntityFramework.dll". Access to the path
>   'D:\Builds\74\653\bin\EntityFramework.dll' is denied. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>   (3797): Unable to copy file
>   "D:\Builds\74\653\src\References\EntityFramework.dll" to
>   "D:\Builds\74\653\bin\EntityFramework.dll". Access to the path
>   'D:\Builds\74\653\bin\EntityFramework.dll' is denied. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>   (3797): Unable to copy file
>   "D:\Builds\74\653\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll"
>   to "D:\Builds\74\653\bin\EntityFramework.dll". Access to the path
>   'D:\Builds\74\653\bin\EntityFramework.dll' is denied. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>   (3797): Unable to copy file
>   "D:\Builds\74\653\src\References\EntityFramework.dll" to
>   "D:\Builds\74\653\bin\EntityFramework.dll". Access to the path
>   'D:\Builds\74\653\bin\EntityFramework.dll' is denied. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>   (3797): Unable to copy file
>   "D:\Builds\74\653\src\EY.MDM\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll"
>   to "D:\Builds\74\653\bin\EntityFramework.dll". Access to the path
>   'D:\Builds\74\653\bin\EntityFramework.dll' is denied. Other Errors  1
>   error(s)  Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You
>   can find more specific information about the cause of this error in
>   above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException) Exception Stack
>   Trace: at
>   System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: I stared a build manually with /p:BuildInParallel=false. It is completed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please also try to manually build it on the build agent.If you get same result.
Possible duplicate with this question [TFS 2012 Build "Access to Path Denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905693/tfs-2012-build-access-to-path-denied)

You can try to use the workaroud in *Mike Asdf*'s answer

> - Obviously one way to prevent the issue is to explicitly run msbuild    with /p:BuildInParallel=false or /m:1 or /maxcpucount:1 (or omit the
>     argument entirely) to force single-threaded mode.
> - Another workaround I attempted was to manually pass    /p:AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions=none to msbuild, which
>     prevents all pdb and xml files from being copied from referenced
>     libraries.
> - The ultimate workaround that I used was one I discovered by    decompiling the source code for `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy`

Comment: tried both first two option and able to run with them.